# layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap" not correctly wrapping TextView

Tags: android

I was having trouble getting some views to wrap to the correct height while matching constraints, and I managed to condense my issue down to a single text view.

For some reason, when I'm using layout_constrainedWidth and layout_constrainedHeight, they can't handle text views that just barely wrap onto the next line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="If a single word wraps onto the next line it is cut off one"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm actually using it on a scroll view that contains some text views, and it doesn't work at all unless I also apply it to the child views as well.

Is this a bug in Android?

Comment: hello brother add  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: If you use wrap_content instead of 0dp then it will wrap content even if that makes it violate its constraints. I am actually trying to use this on a scroll view in a popup. So the popup should wrap the scroll view if the scrollview is smaller than its constraints, but if its too big to fit in its constraints, then it becomes scrollable.

Comment: I was having a similar problem. I had a scrollview inside a constraintLayout. And I wanted the scrollview to match some constraints, but wrap content if the content was less than the constraints. It wasn't working, but then I changed the width to match_parent instead of 0dp and let the constraints start and end to parent do their work. This made it work, so I guess only one of the directions (height, width) can be calculated, if it needs to do both then if fails. Maybe this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was a bug in Android.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123551995

Google marked it as resolved with the release of ConstraintLayout 2.0 beta 2